# IOKit claims libz.dylib is wrong version, but it isn't

Tags: iokit, libz

Here is the error:

> dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
>     Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
>     Reason: Incompatible library version: IOKit requires version 1.0.0 or later, 
>             but **libz.1.dylib provides version 0.0.0**

However:

```
otool -L /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
```

returns

> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib:
>           /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version **1.2.5**)
>           /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)

What am I missing?